# How to Ensure User Sessions Sync with Database Changes in Next.js 14.1 using Next-Auth JWT Strategy?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm encountering an issue with Next-Auth's JWT strategy in a Next.js 14.1 application. I have a MongoDB user model, and when I update this model for a user who is currently logged in, the changes don't reflect in the user's session. For instance, if I directly modify a user's role in the database while they're logged in, their session doesn't update to reflect this change. How can I ensure that user sessions run in sync with database changes?

- I'm using next-auth with JWT strategy.
- My Next.js version is 14.1.
- I have a user model stored in MongoDB.
- When I update this model for a user who is already logged in, the changes aren't reflected in their session.
- For example, modifying a user's role directly in the database doesn't update their session.

**Goal:** I want the user session to automatically synchronize with any changes made to the user model in the database, ensuring that users always have the most up-to-date information during their session.